# How to accurately get the time when a target viewholder comes to the top of recyclerview?

Tags: java, android

I have a recyclerview of comments in a liveroom, user's comment will insert at the bottom of the recyclerview in real time, that is to say early comments will be pushed up, I want to do something when a given item comes to the top just in time.

I've tried addOnScrollListener#onScrolled, but the callbacks are not continuous, they just like 102,58,14,-25..., I fail to get the time when top == 0, what should I do?

```
mMsgRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    View targetView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);
                    int top = targetView == null ? 1 : targetView.getTop();
                    if (top < -AndroidUtils.dip2px(mContext, 3f)) {
                        doSomething();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: You could check the item position in the `onViewAttachedToWindow` or the `onBindViewHolder` in the Adapter maybe. Another idea would be to add the item in the list, get its index and get the ViewHolder by position via `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition`.